# R package for post js load webscraping without relying on an external headless browser

Tags: r, web-scraping, cross-platform, headless-browser, collaboration

I need to scrape content and sniff network activity from an asynchronous web page using R.
The problem is that in my team we work both on Mac and Windows machines on a project directory shared via github.

This creates quite some problem in using external headless browsers via RSelenium (mac/windows path differences, different locations of executables, dynamic number of collaborators).

So an ideal solution would be to use some simple headless browser written directly in R and installed as a package, so that we don't have to take care of OS support, location, etc...

Does such a package exist?

Comment: Seems like you could do some basic setup in an if statement detecting the current OS

Comment: it would mean find the headless browser executable in a number of different computers. I would like to keep the repo clean. Of course if there is not a better alternative I'd adapt

Comment: I found the https://github.com/rstudio/chromote package which seems to do what I need, since it abstract all OS specific tasks and retrieve the installed version of Chrome. 
Now I need to understand how to use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are now solutions to do this through packages like https://github.com/rstudio/chromote or https://github.com/RLesur/crrri without installing any headless browser since recently Chrome exposes an API for interacting with it.